# Hide content if nothing was entered in field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new to this and trying to figure it out. Thank you so much for taking a look!

This works: When on the form (index.html) when user selects 'include' radio the content is shown on the form then also on welcome.php after submit. It's hidden from both otherwise.

The problem: I also would like to do the same and hide the content from being displayed on welcome.php if nothing is entered in fields 'animalvillas1', 'animalvillas2' & 'animalvillas3' independantly.

Please see index.html & welcome.php below:

index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='animalvillas']").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes1").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvanimalvillas").show();
            } else {
                $("#dvanimalvillas").hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<form name="create" action="welcome.php" method="post">
<span><strong>Lodge Villas - Jambo</strong></span><BR />
<label for="chkYes1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="animalvillas" value="Y" />
    Include
</label>
<label for="chkNo1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo1" name="animalvillas" value="N" checked />
    Exclude
</label>
<hr />
<div id="dvanimalvillas" style="display: none">
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas1" size="3" /> - Value Studio - Standard View (Parking View) <br>
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas2" size="3" /> - Deluxe Studio - Standard View (Water / Pool) <br>
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas3" size="3" /> - Deluxe Studio - Savanna View <br>
</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

welcome.php

```
<div id="dvanimalvillas"  <?php echo ($_POST['animalvillas'] == "N") ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ; ?>>
    <?php 
        $animalvillas1 = $_POST["animalvilas1"];
        $animalvillas2 = $_POST["animalvilas2"];
        $animalvillas3 = $_POST["animalvilas3"];

        if(!empty($animalvillas1)){
            echo "$".$_POST["animalvilas1"]." - Value Studio - Standard View <BR>";
        }
        if(!empty($animalvillas2)){
            echo "$".$_POST["animalvilas2"]." - Deluxe Studio - Standard View <BR>";
        }
        if(!empty($animalvillas3)){
            echo "$".$_POST["animalvilas3"]." - Deluxe Studio - Savanna View <BR>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get the problem. Whats your precise question?

Comment: This is not working correctly. When I submit, welcome.php is blank. What is wrong?

Comment: @plzdonthackme This is not your question !! the question is that you want to : *hide the content from being displayed on welcome.php if nothing is entered in fields 'animalvillas1', 'animalvillas2' & 'animalvillas3' independantly.*

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `welcome.php` you can add this:

```
$hide = $_POST['animalvillas'] === "N" || ( 
            empty($_POST["animalvilas1"]) 
            && empty($_POST["animalvilas2"]) 
            && empty($_POST["animalvilas3"]));

<div id="dvanimalvillas"  <?php echo $hide ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ; ?>>
    <?php ....  ?>
</div>
```

This will hide the content if `$_POST['animalvillas'] === "N"` Or all the inputs are empty !

I hope this will help.